# How to load a NodeSeq from a string?

Tags: xml, scala

Scala code:

```
val str = "<a>11</a><b>22</b>"
XML.loadString(str)
```

It will report an exception(of course):

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:
The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
```

Is it possible to load a NodeSeq from the string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parser in scala doesn't like your example string

```
val str2="<xml><a>11</a><b>22</b></xml>"
```

works just fine, I guess that your example doesn't count as a complete document

To get the elements "inside" the `<xml>..</xml>` do this

```
val n = xml.XML.loadString(str2)
val list = n.child
```

which returns a List

```
scala> n.child
res12: Seq[scala.xml.Node] = List(<a>11</a>, <b>22</b>)
```

Comment: If I add a root node, it will working, but I have to remove the root manually.

Comment: I've added a method to remove the "root" and just have the two fragments as list elements.  Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, this may be the only solution

Answer (score 1):

To supplement Vorsprung's answer, the actual *reason* why `XML.loadString` fails on the input `<a>11</a><b>22</b>` is just what the exception tells you (emphasis mine):

> The markup in the document following the root element **must be
>   well-formed**.

One of the requirements of a *[well-formed](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-well-formed)* XML document is that it contains **exactly one root element**.

Thus, for example this works fine and gives you a `NodeSeq` (an `Elem` to be more exact):

```
XML.loadString("<c><a>11</a><b>22</b></c>")
```